# Indy10 ConnectTimeout minimal value

Tags: connection, timeout, client, freepascal, indy10

I have a problem regarding the `ConnectTimeout` from Indy 10's `TIdTCPClient`.

When setting the `ConnectTimeout` higher than 125ms the `Connect()` procedure will block the current thread for 125ms. If it is less than 125ms, it will block for the given time (e.g. it blocks for 30ms if the timeout is set to 30ms). In both cases, the connection is stable and I can transmit and receive data.

Why is the `TIdTCPClient` behaving like that?

IMHO the `Connect()` procedure should exit directly after the connection is successfully made and only block the full duration of the timeout if no connection can be opened.

Here's my code for monitoring the duration of the `Connect()` procedure.
The timer for calling `TimerConnectTimer` is set to 250ms.

I am using Lazarus v1.6.4 and Indy 10 under Windows 7 Professional.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  timer := TEpikTimer.create(self);
  timer.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.TimerConnectTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  timer.Start;
  client := TIdTCPClient.create();
  logTime(0);
  // Tested with values between 10ms and 1000ms
  client.ConnectTimeout := SpinEdit1.Value;
  try
    logTime(1);
    // choose ip and port for a running server
    client.connect('192.168.2.51', 9912);
    logTime(2);
  except

  end;

  logTime(3);

  try
    client.Disconnect();
    FreeAndNil(client);
  except

  end;

  logTime(4);
  timer.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.logTime(ch: integer);
begin
  StringGrid1.Cells[0, ch] := FormatFloat('0.00', timer.Elapsed*1000);
end;
```

Comment: Which exact version of Indy 10 are you using?  It makes a difference in how `ConnectTimeout` behaves.

Comment: I am using Indy version 10.6.2.0.

Comment: is it actually `.0` (that is VERY old), or is it really a newer version that just doesn't have the SVN revision in its version number? Where did you get Indy from exactly, and when? Since you are using FreePascal, you could just update to the latest snapshot (even install it using Lazarus' OPM).

Answer (score 0):

> When setting the `ConnectTimeout` higher than 125ms the `Connect()` procedure will block the current thread for 125ms. If it is less than 125ms, it will block for the given time (e.g. it blocks for 30ms if the timeout is set to 30ms). In both cases, the connection is stable and I can transmit and receive data.
>
> Why is the `TIdTCPClient` behaving like that?

That is hard to answer without knowing which version of Indy 10 you are using exactly, as the implementation of `ConnectTimeout` has changed over the years.  But, in general:

If `ConnectTimeout` is set to `IdTimeoutDefault` or `0`, `IdTimeoutInfinite` is used instead.

If `Connect()` is called in the main UI thread, `TIdAntiFreeze` is being used, and an infinite timeout is used, a hard-coded 2min timeout is used instead.

If any timeout is used, `Connect()` spawns a worker thread to connect the socket to the server, and then waits up to the timeout for the thread to terminate.  If the timeout elapses before the thread terminates, Indy closes the socket and terminates the thread.

Assuming you are using a fairly up-to-date version of Indy 10 (at least SVN revision 5382 on Dec 14 2016, or later), and are not using `TIdAntiFreeze`, then on Windows only, the wait *should* exit immediately when the worker thread terminates, as Indy makes a single call to `WaitForSingleObject()` on the thread for the full timeout and exits as soon as `WFSO` exits.

If you are using `TIdAntiFreeze`, or are using Indy on a non-Windows platform, or are using a version of Indy 10 prior to SVN rev 5382, the wait calls `IndySleep()` (and if needed, `TIdAntiFreeze.DoProcess()`) in a loop at fixed intervals (125ms, or `TIdAntiFreeze.IdleTimeOut`, whichever is smaller) until the timeout is exceeded or the thread has terminated.  In which case, there *may* be a slight delay before `Connect()` exits, as each sleep cycle has to complete before `Connect()` can check if the thread has terminated, and do so for every sleep interval within the overall connect timeout.

> IMHO the `Connect()` procedure should exit directly after the connection is successfully made and only block the full duration of the timeout if no connection can be opened.

That is exactly what it currently does, on Windows at least.  If the connection is successful, the thread terminates, and `Connect()` exits immediately (even if `TIdAntiFreeze` is used).  The current sleep cycle is ended by the thread terminating itself.  That is not the case on non-Windows platforms (for now, may be addressed in a future version).

Note that all of the above only applies when a timeout is used.  If no timeout is used, no worker thread is used, either.  `Connect()` simply connects the socket directly and lets the attempt block the calling thread until finished, whether successful or not.

> Here's my code for monitoring the duration of the `Connect()` procedure.

I would suggest something more like this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.TimerConnectTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    timer.Start;
    try
      logTime(0);

      client := TIdTCPClient.create();
      try
        // choose ip and port for a running server
        client.Host := '192.168.2.51';
        client.Post := 9912;

        // Tested with values between 10ms and 1000ms
        client.ConnectTimeout := SpinEdit1.Value;

        logTime(1);
        client.Connect();
        logTime(2);
        client.Disconnect();
        logTime(3);

      finally
        FreeAndNil(client);
      end;

      logTime(4);
    finally
      timer.Clear;
    end;
  except
  end;
end;
```